# Waiting for async function in React component & Showing Spinner

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-apollo

Beginner here.

Trying to fetch some data from a server and display it in my react component once its fetched.
However, I am having trouble integrating the async function into my react component.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { request } from "graphql-request";

async function fetchData() {
  const endpoint = "https://localhost:3090/graphql"

  const query = `
    query getItems($id: ID) {
      item(id: $id) {
        title
      }
    }
  `;

  const variables = {
    id: "123123123"
  };

  const data = await request(endpoint, query, variables);
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

  return data;
}

const TestingGraphQL = () => {
  const data = fetchData().catch((error) => console.error(error));

  return (
    <div>
      {data.item.title}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestingGraphQL;
```

I'd like to simply show a spinner or something while waiting, but I tried this & it seems because a promise is returned I cannot do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you would need to use the `useEffect` hook to call the API.
The `data` returned from the API, I am storing here in a state, as well as a `loading` state to indicate when the call is being made.

Follow along the comments added in between the code below -

**CODE**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"; // importing useEffect here
import Layout from "@layouts/default";
import ContentContainer from "@components/ContentContainer";
import { request } from "graphql-request";

async function fetchData() {
   const endpoint = "https://localhost:3090/graphql"

   const query = `
     query getItems($id: ID) {
       item(id: $id) {
         title
       }
     }
   `;

   const variables = {
      id: "123123123"
   };

   const data = await request(endpoint, query, variables);
   // console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

   return data;
}

const TestingGraphQL = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  
  // useEffect with an empty dependency array works the same way as componentDidMount
  useEffect(async () => {
     try {
       // set loading to true before calling API
       setLoading(true);
       const data = await fetchData();
       setData(data);
       // switch loading to false after fetch is complete
       setLoading(false);
     } catch (error) {
       // add error handling here
       setLoading(false);
       console.log(error);
     }
  }, []);

  // return a Spinner when loading is true
  if(loading) return (
    <span>Loading</span>
  );

  // data will be null when fetch call fails
  if (!data) return (
    <span>Data not available</span>
  );

  // when data is available, title is shown
  return (
    <Layout>
      {data.item.title}
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Comment: **SUGGESTION** - since you are working with GraphQL here, I would suggest you check `@apollo/client`. The setup might take some time, but once done, you can do something like `const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(query);` instead of all that code. Check out their documentation [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/). Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. As for apollo: I actually have it working with apollo right now and am switching to `graphql-request` because I want to use redux and not have state in two places.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. However, integrating your app's redux store with apollo-client's is also possible, I think. Check this [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/apollo-docs-1.x/redux.html), maybe this would be helpful. Anyway, did the answer help you solve the loading issue?

Comment: Oh, so this means i wouldn't have to use Apollos own state management then? Because that was my main problem, I wanted to use redux instead, and combining it with Apollo wouldve meant having no single source of truth

Comment: Yes, I understand. The link I shared above will guide you to use your own redux store, which would include Apollos state management as well. You would have a single source of truth, and can add your own reducers and states on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

since `fetchData()` returns a promise you need to handle it in `TestingGraphQL`. I recommend `onComponentMount` do your data call. Setting the data retrieved into the `state` var, for react to keep track of and re-rendering when your data call is finished.

I added a loading state var. If loading is true, then it shows 'loading' otherwise it shows the data. You can go about changing those to components later to suit your needs.

See the example below, switched from hooks to a class, but you should be able to make it work! :)

```
class TestingGraphQL extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: {}, loading: true};
  }
  
  //when the component is added to the screen. fetch data
  componentDidMount() {
    fetchData()
      .then(json => { this.setState({ data: json, loading: false }) })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
  
  render() {
     return (
      {this.state.loading ? <div>Loading Spinner here</div> : <div>{this.state.data.item.title}</div>}
    );
  }
};
```