# Append array from constructor in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this class component where I'd like to fetch the response from server to an state array so I can pass further the elements to another component as props, so far I have this:

```
export default class MainApp extends Component {
state = {
    posts: [],
}

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    const request = new FetchRequest();
    request.setAmount(this.props.amount);
    request.setUserid(this.props.token);
    request.setSeenpostsList(this.props.seenPosts);
    
    var stream = client.fetchPosts(request, {});
    stream.on('data', function(response) {
        this.setState({
            posts: [...this.state.posts, response.array]
        })
    });
}

render(){
    return(
    <div className="main-app">
        <Navbar />
        <Postbox token = {this.props.token}/>
        {this.state.posts.map(element => 
            <Postcard username = {element[0]}/>
         )}
    </div>
    )
}
```

With this code I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'posts')`.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You have a race condition here. You're launching an asynchronous request from the constructor, and your component is being rendered (and accessing the to-be-populated state variable) before the request has completed. Your template needs some sort of switch based on the presence of the state variable. Common practice would be to display a loading indicator while the state variable is `null` or `undefined` (using `== null`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63192621/2869332

Answer (score 1):

Your state needs to be initialised within the `constructor() {}`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    posts: []
  }
}
```

Here's [info](https://daveceddia.com/where-initialize-state-react/) you might also want to read